# Submit form via Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

So, I followed a tutorial [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/?search_index=1) to be able to submit a form with ajax. I followed the tutorial exactly (atleast I thought I did) and when I try to submit the form the page just refreshes and it never gets to the php script to send it to the database.

The script that I am using is below:

```
$(function () {
$(".button").click(function () {
    $(function () {
        $('.error').hide();
        $("#submit_btn").click(function () {
            //validate and process form here

            $('.error').hide();
            var firstname = $("input#firstname").val();
            if (firstname == "") {
                $("label#firstname_error").show();
                $("input#firstname").focus();
                return false;
            }

            var lastname = $("input#lastname").val();
            if (lastname == "") {
                $("label#lastname_error").show();
                $("input#lastname").focus();
                return false;
            }

            var email = $("input#email").val();
            if (email == "") {
                $("label#email_error").show();
                $("input#email").focus();
                return false;
            }

            var pin = $("input#parent_pin").val();
            if (pin == "") {
                $("label#parent_pin_error").show();
                $("input#parent_pin").focus();
                return false;
            }

            var login = $("input#login").val();
            if (login == "") {
                $("label#login_error").show();
                $("input#login").focus();
                return false;
            }

            var passwd = $("input#passwd").val();
            if (passwd == "") {
                $("label#passwd_error").show();
                $("input#passwd").focus();
                return false;
            }

            var cpasswd = $("input#cpasswd").val();
            if (cpasswd == "") {
                $("label#cpasswd_error").show();
                $("input#cpasswd").focus();
                return false;
            }

            var user_type = $("input#user_type").val();
            if (user_type == "") {
                $("label#user_type_error").show();
                $("input#user_type").focus();
                return false;
            }

            var dataString = 'firstname=' + firstname + '&lastname=' + lastname + '&email=' + email + '&parent_pin=' + pin + '&login='
            login + '&passwd='
            passwd + 'user_type' = user_type;
            //alert (dataString);return false;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "studentAccess/files/AddNewUser.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function () {
                    $('#form-body').html("<div id='message'></div>");
                    $('#message').html("<h2>New User Added Successfully!</h2>");

                }
            });
        });
    });
  });
});
```

The error that I am receiving in Google Chrome's console is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier AddNewUser.js:65
```

Line 65 would be:

```
var dataString = 'firstname=' + firstname + '&lastname=' + lastname + '&email=' + email + '&parent_pin=' + pin + '&login=' login + '&passwd=' passwd + 'user_type' = user_type;
```

I'm not sure how to fix this problem because I don't know what the error means. Any help would be great!

**UPDATE**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO members (firstname, lastname, email, login, psswd, user_type)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[email]', '$_POST[login]', '$_POST[psswd]', '$_POST[user_type]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: `'&passwd=' passwd + 'user_` missing +

Comment: Different problem: you're not properly URL-encoding those components. What if enduser enters spaces/quotes/ampersands/etc in the input values? Plus, this approach is clumsy. Checkout http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ and eventually http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ + http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: To stop the page from refreshing (to stop the default button click behavior, you could try modifying your submit button click handler to this: `$("#submit_btn").click(function (event) { event.preventDefault(); ...`.

Comment: @Jrop -- The script should work just like what it came like from the tutorial... It did in the demo.

Comment: @user2673735: In the tutorial, at the end of the AJAX there is a `return false;` statement which is missing in your code. This causes the refresh. You can solve this by either adding the missing line (or) adding `event.preventDefault()` as mentioned by Jrop and also in my answer. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the below line, it should be `'&user_type=' + user_type;` instead of `'user_type' = user_type;`

```
var dataString = 'firstname=' + firstname + '&lastname=' + lastname + '&email=' + email + '&parent_pin=' + pin + '&login=' login + '&passwd=' passwd + 'user_type' = user_type;
```

Also, if the button is a `submit` button, you should prevent the default form submit action using `event.preventDefault();` within the button's `click` event.

In addition, the first two lines of code is not required. I have commented them out.

```
/*$(function () {
$(".button").click(function () {*/

    $(function () {
        $('.error').hide();
        $("#submit_btn").click(function (event) { 
            event.preventDefault();
            //rest of your current validation code should be put here.
        });
     });
```

Comment: Will you provide exactly how the `event.preventDefault();` should look like in my script.

Comment: Ok I am not getting the form to "submit" without page refreshing. But now nothing is showing up in the database. The php script is just fine. So it has to be something within the ajax.

Comment: @user2673735: Is that a typo (or) are you still "not getting the form to submit"? Also, are you getting the AJAX success message? Check console to see if there are any errors.

Comment: I AM getting the form to submit without page refresh. But nothing is showing up in the database. Meaning the information isn't getting to the php script.

Comment: You can see my updated script here: http://www.usd309bands.org/studentAccess/files/AddNewUser.js

Comment: @user2673735 add `alert("success");` within the `success: function () {` and see if the alert comes up.

Comment: @user2673735 Also, there is one more issue, you seem to be missing an `&` before the `'user_type'` in the line `'&passwd=' + passwd + 'user_type=' + user_type;`

Comment: It's displaying the form values in the URL as if it is doing it with GET instead of POST

Comment: where are you seeing this URL? in the address bar of the browser? that shouldn't be happening. Or are you seeing it in the console? I tried a dummy call with your same `$.ajax` code and it doesn't show the form values.

Comment: It is showing up in the address bar of the browser. Let me try to change my POST to GET in the php script and see what happens.

Comment: Still nothing in the database.

Comment: Is there any place where I can see your full code (HTML, JS and PHP) in working? It might be easier to figure out the errors that way rather than guessing the rest of your code.

Comment: You need to show your php code. How you are connecting to and inserting into the database could be incorrect.

Comment: There is your problem: you are not connecting to any database with your $con. You need `$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","my_db");` localhost is your host/IP, username and password are how you login to your database, and my_db is your database name.

Comment: First thing I noted, the variable in datastring is `passwd` whereas the one in the insert statement is `psswd`. Next, can you add some echo statements to see if (a) the PHP page is called and (b) if it is getting the parameter values correctly. (I have limited experience with PHP/mySQL)

Comment: @Chad, I am making a connection, I removed it for security purposes.

Comment: @Harry, We never see the page so we can't

Comment: It isn't a problem with PHP it's a problem with Javascript

Comment: Try this: `"INSERT INTO members (firstname, lastname, email, login, passwd, user_type)
VALUES ('test','test','test','test','test','test')"` just to make sure you are able to insert ANYTHING into your db through the $con.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that you do not have quotes when using $_POST[]. Try adding quotes to all of them and see if that works. `('$_POST["firstname"]','$_POST["lastname"]','$_POST["email"]', '$_POST["login"]', '$_POST["passwd"]', '$_POST["user_type"]')`

Answer (score 1):

You have missed `+` symbols in the #65 line

Should be

```
var dataString = 'firstname=' + firstname + '&lastname=' + lastname + '&email=' + email + '&parent_pin=' + pin + '&login=' + login + '&passwd=' + passwd + '&user_type=' + user_type;
```

Please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax

Remove `$(function () {` in `.button` click handler. Now it just registers a handle on button click but not executes it

Comment: Ok so I fixed that but it still doesn't submit the form without refreshing the page. And it still isn't sending the information to the php script.

Comment: So it needs to be just `.button.click` I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

At the very end of that line you have:

```
'user_type' = user_type;
```

It needs to be:

```
'&user_type=' + user_type;
```

You may also need to add `return false;` after your ajax to prevent the page from refreshing (and clearing out your form).

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "studentAccess/files/AddNewUser.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function () {
        $('#form-body').html("<div id='message'></div>");
        $('#message').html("<h2>New User Added Successfully!</h2>");
    }
});
return false; //Keep page from refreshing
```

Further EDIT:

You also have a `.click()` embedded in a `.click()`. You cannot click two buttons at one time. You need to change this:

```
$(function () {
$(".button").click(function () {
    $(function () {
        $('.error').hide();
        $("#submit_btn").click(function () {
```

to this...

```
$(function () {
    $('.error').hide();
    $("#submit_btn").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ...
```

Comment: OK, so I fixed that but the page still just refreshes and the form isn't actually submitted.

Comment: Try adding `return false;` after your ajax and see if that does the trick.

Comment: No. Still just refreshes the page after  I click submit.

Comment: Made another change. You cannot embed `.click()` functions inside other `.click()` functions. You can't click two buttons at once.